# Automatically reposition UI elements with IB

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I'm originally an Android developer starting with iOS now, but I'm having some problems to do something quite simple: reposition the UI elements based on other UI elements. For example, see the following picture:

[image]

**Image 1:** I created a layout with an image, a label and two buttons.

**Image 2:** I programmatically hid the image, then the label and the two buttons repositioned themselves and took the place where the image was originally located.

I know this can be done programmatically but is there a way to achieve the same behavior using only the Interface Builder? It's really simple to do that in Android so I hope we can do the same for iOS.

Comment: wt u want u want to hide UIImage by using XIB ??

Comment: You can't do this only in IB. You'll have to give the text view the origin.y of the image view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in IB, if u hide the image programmatically.
It' not like android U have to drag it or adjust the size inspector in xib file for iOS befor execution.

In xib file all are static, if u want to make any changes during execution u should do it by programmatically.

ie, set the frame for label(I think u are using Textview) and button to the imageview's frame

or

do it by using tableview add the imageview, label,button programmatically

Comment: Is it possible to do easily with Auto Layout in iOS6?